# Update the content of share intent in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I have created a sharing icon using the `ShareActionProvider`. In the `MainActivity` class I have the following:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
 ....
 private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;
 ...
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        // Locate MenuItem with ShareActionProvider
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);
        // Fetch and store ShareActionProvider
        mShareActionProvider =
                (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(item);

        // call the intent
        setShareIntent();
        return true;
    }

    private void setShareIntent() {

        Intent myShareIntent = new Intent();
        myShareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        myShareIntent.setType("text/plain");

        // get the content of the text view
        myShareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, myTextView.getText());

        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(myShareIntent);

    }
```

The problem is that the content of the `myTextView` changes and when the user clicks the share icon, the default text is shared.

I think this is because we are calling the intent in the `onCreateOptionsMenu`. How can I update the intent so it gets the current content stored in `myTextView`?

Answer (score 1):

Hold onto the `Intent` in a field of your `Activity`, and call `putExtra()` on the field when the value to be shared changes.

In [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/ActionBar/ShareNative/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/sap/MainActivity.java), I have an `EditText` and want to update the `Intent` extra when the user types stuff in:

```
/***
  Copyright (c) 2012 CommonsWare, LLC
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain   a copy
  of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
  by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
  License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
  OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
  language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

  From _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
    https://commonsware.com/Android
 */

package com.commonsware.android.sap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ShareActionProvider;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
    ShareActionProvider.OnShareTargetSelectedListener, TextWatcher {
  private ShareActionProvider share=null;
  private Intent shareIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  private EditText editor=null;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    editor=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editor);
    editor.addTextChangedListener(this);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.actions, menu);

    share=
        (ShareActionProvider)menu.findItem(R.id.share)
                                 .getActionProvider();
    share.setOnShareTargetSelectedListener(this);

    return(super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onShareTargetSelected(ShareActionProvider source,
                                       Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(this, intent.getComponent().toString(),
                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    return(false);
  }

  @Override
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, s.toString());
    share.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
  }

  @Override
  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                int after) {
    // ignored
  }

  @Override
  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                            int count) {
    // ignored
  }
}
```

I elect to not only update the extra, but also to call `setShareIntent()` again. I do not know if that is necessary.

Comment: sorry this is very confusing, so create the intent in the `onCreate` ?

Comment: @RainMan: I actually create the `Intent` in a field initializer, since it does not depend upon a `Context` or anything. I could create a brand-new `Intent` object on every `afterTextChanged()` call, but that seemed wasteful.

Answer (score 0):

You should override the following method:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    //your code
}
```

And call your method `setShareIntent()` there. This is of course if you want to trigger that behavior on options click, if you have another button or something, just add `onClickListener` to it.